# Travel within Schengen Business visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland

I will go to Switzerland as a visiting scholar for one month. I have already got a Schengen business visa. In my application, I provided the invitation letter. A proof of accommodation offered by my friend. I did not specify any travel plan in the visa application.

In the meanwhile, my girlfriend wants to join me and travel with me at the end of my stay (the last 8 days of my visiting). She needs a Schengen tourism visa. She wishes that I could provide a copy of my Schengen visa in her visa application. She hopes to live with me in airbnb. We will only travel within Switzerland. I have two questions:

First, since I did not specify any travel plan in my visa application, and my visa is a business visa, would this be questioned by the visa officer that I "cheated" in my visa application?

Second, since this last 8 days I will not live in my friend's place, would this be questioned by the visa officer that I "cheated" in my visa application?

She does not need to depend on me financially. But I do not know whether my copy of visa would cause any trouble for her application, as well as for my already approved visa.

This is really a tricky situation, I will appreciate if you could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance!